# yii2 display search filter and field from another table

Tags: php, yii2

I have this in my controller departments class:

Hello guys

So there is something i am trying to achieve with yii

I have a Departments table and a student table. Inside the students view i want to show the departments name and the filter. 
    While i am able to display the department name for each student but the department name filter doesn't show.

Below is my code with comments:

```
/*Begining of Students model*/

class Students extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
```

/* this is where i did a reference to my students table*/

```
public function getDepartments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Departments::className(), ['department_id' => 'ID']);
}
```

--- End of Students model

--- Begining of Students View

```
/*Inside my view folder i have the Students folder where i have an index.php file where everything is listed in Gridview. */
```

View/Students/index.php

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\grid\GridView;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use app\models\States;
use kartik\export\ExportMenu;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $searchModel app\models\AgentsSearch */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

$this->title = 'Agents';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;


$gridColumns = [
    ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
    'created_at',
    'name',
    departments.name',
    'status',
    ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],

];


// Renders a export dropdown menu
echo ExportMenu::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => $gridColumns
]);

    ?>
    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'tableOptions' =>['class'=>'table table-bordered'], 
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => $gridColumns
    ]); ?>
</div>



/*End of Students view*/



/*Begining of Students search.*/


/*models/StudentsSearch.php*/
```

I understand that the code below inside my StudentsSearch.php file is responsible for displaying the filter for each field.

```
  public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['phone'], 'integer'],
            //my understanding is that this is what controls the filter form, only fields listed here have filters
            [['phone','name' 'email', 'address','city','departments.name'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }

/*End of Students search.*/
```

I am able to show filter for every other thing but how do i show filter for the department name?

Comment: There are somethings wrong in your `Students`. The `getDepartments` function should be `return $this->hasMany(Departments::class, ['ID' => 'department_id']);`

Comment: Thanks @ Paul made the correction, still not getting the desired result

Comment: i don't think 'departments.name' in rules has any effect. never saw this before

Answer (score 0):

read this: https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/851/yii2-gridview-sorting-and-searching-with-a-junction-table-columnmany-to-many-relationship

1. add a new property to your `StudentsSearch`, e.g. `$departmentName`
2. add this property to StudentsSearch's rules, e.g. `[['departmentName'], 'safe']`
3. use 'departmentName' in your query, e.g. `$query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'department.name', $this->departmentName])`

sorting on a calculated field works similar, read this: https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/621/filter-sort-by-calculatedrelated-fields-in-gridview-yii-2-0

```
$dataProvider->setSort([
    'attributes' => [
        'id',
        'departmentName' => [
            'asc'     => ['department.name' => SORT_ASC],
            'desc'    => ['department.name' => SORT_DESC],
            'label'   => 'Department',
            'default' => SORT_ASC
        ],
    ]
]);
```

Comment: Hi, regarding the third istruction, is it possible to search by an ID ?
Let's say that in the StudentTable the Department is stored with an ID but for a better user experience you need to search it directly with the DepartmentName, how is it possible to perform this task ?

Comment: you can use any property in the joined table, so you can just replace "name" by "id".

Answer (score 0):

1. in the studentsSearch class add department to the rules.

Make reference to the Departments table by adding it to the rules.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
    //this controls the filter section, only fields listed here will have filter
    [['Department'], 'safe'],
    ];
```

}

2. Then in Students view in this case in my index.php i add the attribute "departments" and make reference to the deparment name using departments.name in my gridColumns

   ```
   $gridColumns = [
   ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
   'name',
   'email:email',
   'address',

   [
       'attribute' => 'departments',
       'label' => Department Name',
       'value' => 'department.name'
   ],

   'status',
   ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
   ];


   ?>
   ```
3. in students model inside your attributeLabels method add the departments.name attribute.

   public function attributeLabels()
   {
       'Department.name' => 'Department Name'
   }